# Css file is generated in pub/static folder but looking at source file in browser it is not listed

Tags: magento2, overrides, css, code-generation

After deploying my theme I see that the `mycustom-m.css` file is generated at `/pub/static/frontend/Vendor/mytheme/en_US/css/mycustom-m.css`, but it does not make any changes. Looking at the source file in browser I realized that it's not listed, however I have below code in default_head_blocks.xml

```
<head>
        <css src="css/mycustom-m.css" order="100" />
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Add your css **Namespace/Module/View/frontend/web/css/mycustom-m.css**

```
<css src="Namespace_Module::css/mycustom-m.css"/>
```

Try this steps.

1. Create css file under this directory.
   **app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/web/css/mycustom-m.css**
2. Create **default_head_blocks.xml** file if not exist at this path
   **app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml**

Put below code in **default_head_blocks.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
        <css src="css/mycustom-m.css" />
    </head>
</page>
```

Comment: I'm not building module, I'm working on child theme and the path of the file is /app/design/frontend/Vendor/mytheme/web/css/mycustom-m.css

Comment: Check my updated answer

Comment: That's exactly what I have, but wondering why it is not listed in source file.

Comment: Flush your cache

Comment: Ok Please run this cmd : php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47250/discussion-between-zinat-and-kothari).

Comment: The same, Css file is generated in pub/static folder but looking at source file in browser it is not listed